# Swipe only one item at a time in ViewPager using moondroid

Tags: android, reflection, 3d, android-viewpager

I want to implement Reflection 3D effect ViewPager, I have used https://github.com/akhgupta/CoverFlow It's working fine but when I swipe it depends on touch intercept so 2 or 3 items scrolling at a one swipe. I want to swipe only one item at a time instead of more than one.

I tried a lot and I have made changes in library even but I didn't get succeed.

Comment: I have already tried this, i have customized the library but i couldn't found any solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you must download source code libs and add it like module. then custom method have function swipe.

Example code:

```
private float initialX;
private float THRESHOLD;
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    THRESHOLD = getWidth() / 2;
    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = event.getX();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float finalX = event.getX();
            float deltaX = Math.abs(finalX - initialX);
            if (deltaX > THRESHOLD) {
                return false;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            break;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i have tried to customize but It's not working!
Have you an idea about it

Comment: Any one have an idea about it?

Comment: I try test libs. It swipe only item when scroll.

Comment: Yeah but i want swipe only one item on swipe

Comment: current libs swipe only one item on swipe?

Comment: No it's depend on touch **dispatchTouchEvent** of user